# How can we implement incoming UI call screen in java just like in flutter we do with flutter callkit incoming package?

Tags: java, ios, flutter, kotlin, native

I want to show the incoming call UI screen like this https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/1191071/screenshots/9095799/01_incoming_call_whitebg.png?compress=1&resize=400x300 . How can I achieve this in java? Please help.. Is there any prebuilt java or kotlin package to show like this. Because flutter already has one package to show like this.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the following package [Flutter Incoming Call](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_incoming_call). I've used it and it works great.

Comment: I want to do it for java not flutter. Will this help?

Comment: It will work for both Android n IOS. I do not understand why you only want to do it for java.

Comment: I am a java developer so I want to make this functionality in java language.

Comment: Do you have some tutorial for actually implementing this package? Much appreciated.

Comment: @MatějMudra I will get back to you if I find a tutorial for this

Comment: I would very much appreciate that, the app example works fine with the example fake call, but I have trouble setting up the device in a way so that the actual incoming calls would be handled by the app.

Comment: I have looked alot if there was any real implementation of flutter incoming calls. I used this on a previous project that I have no access rn orelse I could've simply share the code. What problem are you facing in an actual incoming calls? If you brief me I can guide you in the right direction

Comment: I am unable to get the app to replace the default calling app. I set it as a default calling app in settings and called from another cellphone. The call was still received by the standard phone app. What I want to do is: 
When someone calls the user from their cell phone (through SIM card, the old way) then screen will be displayed with callers number but also name and additional description from database.

Comment: You need to set your app as the default phone app in your phone. Did you do that from settings -> Default Apps??